# How to display the Null values coming from the Table as blank in Textbox while load from the Gridview?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, c#-3.0

While entering values into the Table, I left few columns in a row are blank, While load it from Gridview to the Textbox, its all storing as "& nbsp;".
I dont want this null value "& nbsp;" to be displayed inside Textboxes, It has to be be empty when i select from Gridview... What i have to do for that?

Comment: are you using any DataSource control to saving record ?

Comment: My problem is when i load values from Grid view to textbox its displaying  as "& nbsp;" if that data field is blank. If any null value is there in table we use isnull method for giving default value.. like that can i assign empty value ??  I tried like this isnull(Middle_Name,'')Middle_Name, but not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using DataSource controls, then set `ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"` to your parameters

```
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
    </InsertParameters>
```

OR if you are using parameterized query then it should be like...

```
if (TextBox1.Text.Trim() = string.Empty)
    {
        // pass the null value as parameter
        //com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@savePath", null);
    }
```

Comment: @Akhtar, for me storing null values is not a problem, when i load values from Grid view to textbox its displaying as "& nbsp;" if that data field is blank. If any null value is there in table we use isnull method for giving default value.. like that can i assign empty value ?? I tried like this isnull(Middle_Name,'')Middle_Name, but not working.. what to give exactly?

Comment: In html &nbsp; = empty space, When you assign empty string to your any control, it will be rendered as &nbsp; in browser. You can check to view the source of browser.

Comment: @Akhtar, yes. Empty space is not a problem, bcoz that textboxes and all not mandatory. I dont want to that Text Boxes displaying "& nbsp;"  What to do for that?

Comment: You can put condition before assigning value, if it is then assign Empty String like... Textbox1.Text = String.Empty;

Answer (score 0):

After assigning value to your TextBox from GridView write the following code:

```
    if(textBoxName.Text == "& nbsp;")
    {
        textBoxName.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(textBoxName.Text);
    }
```

Comment: Do not put a space between & and nbsp; I have done it otherwise it displays just a white space.